# Java class implementing an interface and another class extending this class

Tags: java

I have an java interface which has few abstract methods.

```
public interface Interface {
    void test();
    void test1();
}
```

Now I have a class A that implements Interface. Requirement is I want to extend class A to multiple client classes. Class A should implement test(). Now I want class A should keep test1 abstract and the implementation of test1 should be done in clients of class A. Is it possible to achieve this in Java. If yes, can somebody correct way to implement this requirement ?

Comment: First you give us an interface 'A', then you say you want to 'extend class A'. And then you say 'class A should implement'. This makes no sense.

Comment: That's what. I am new to java. Please suggest how to structure this requirement. If this makes no sense, can you suggest how can I fix this ?

Comment: @cppdev: your class and your interface have the same name (A). This makes no sense in its current form. Please revise your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, every method is an interface is public and abstract by default.  You have no choice.

Here's how I'd write it, with better names:

```
public interface A {
    void test1();
    void test2();
}

public abstract class B implements A {
{
    public void test1() { // do something here; concrete implementation }
    // Note: Nothing for test2.  
    // Compiler doesn't complain because it's an abstract class, and this is an abstract method.
}

public class C extends B {
    // Note: nothing for test1 - get it from abstract superclass
    // Note: compiler will complain if nothing is done to implement test2(), because C isn't abstract
    public void test2() { // do something here; concrete implementation }
}
```

Class `C` can override `test1()` if it chooses to, but if nothing is done it'll inherit the behavior specified in class `B`.

Comment: So do not want test2 should have concrete implementation in class B. Does it makes sense to remove it from interface and make it abstract in class B iteself ?

Comment: See also [When an Abstract Class Implements an Interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html).